# Creating a Rectangle object and finding area

Tags: java, awt, sbt, rectangles

How can I create a Rectangle object and use its methods to determine the area?

I have tried to create a Rectangle object and print it to console like this:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Rectangle
{   
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(5,10,20,30);
        System.out.println(box);            
    }
}
```

I expected it to print the area but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: if you print rectangle in console you could use sout

Comment: You may need this. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawRectangle.htm

Comment: Simply The Question is = write an areatester program to construst an rectangle object and computes and prints its area. use getwidth and get height methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for `Rectangle.toString()`, which is called automatically by `System.out.println`, you will see that it prints out the parameters that make up the `Rectangle` object. However, it will not draw it:

```
return getClass().getName() + "[x=" + x + ",y=" + y + ",width=" + width + ",height=" + height + "]";
```

You're not explicitly calling `toString()`, but impliclty you are: